# ImportError: No module named XXX - Windows Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to run my Python project using Pycharm and Anaconda Virtual Environment on Windows.

I had success running project on Linux, but when I changed to Windows, for some reason it won't find relative paths of my directories.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does the problem perhaps lie in the environment variables or?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: When you say _changed to Windows_, what do you mean? Are you using the same environment? Is PyCharm set up to use Conda?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend verifying the environment that you are working in has config installed, then check environment variables (as per your screen shot)

Comment: config is custom made package